# Installing FLTK on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fltk

I am having some problems installing FLTK 1.3.2 on visual studio 2010. I am unzipping the files, then opening the FLTK.dsw with visual studio, selecting yes to all, then after it is loading I build the solution.  Whenever I try to build the solution I get 80 builds successful , 4 failed , 0 skipped. I think I am doing something wrong because I have tried it on two separate computers and got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Which solution are you building?

If you're using VS2010, then use ide\VisualC2010\fltk.sln to build it.  Make sure you select debug or release.  It defaults to Debug Cairo, which you don't really want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that FLTK is using the [CMake build system](http://www.cmake.org/). CMake can build projects for many different compilers and tools, including native project files for Visual Studio 2010. You should download CMake from their official site and then use cmake-gui, a very straightforward GUI tool that will guide you through the process of generating VS 2010 project files. You then open the project/solution file using Visual Studio and build it like you would build any project created using that software. A kick-start tutorial on running CMake can be found [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/runningcmake.html), for example.